# R creating a function using plyr revalue with multiple inputs

Tags: r, function, plyr

I am new to R and just learning the ropes so thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

I have a dataset that I am cleaning as a class project.

I have several sets of categorical data that I want to turn into specific numeric values.

I am repeating the same code format for different columns that I think would make a good function.

I would like to turn this:

```
# plyr using revalue
df$Area <- revalue(x = df$Area,
                   replace = c("rural" = 1,
                               "suburban" = 2,
                               "urban" = 3))

df$Area <- as.numeric(df$Area)
```

into this:

```
 reval_3 <- function(data, columnX,
                     value1, num_val1,
                     value2, num_val2,
                     value3, num_val3) {

  # plyr using revalue
  data$columnX <- revalue(x = data$columnX,
                        replace = c(value1 = num_val1,
                                    value2 = num_val2,
                                    value3 = num_val3))

  # set as numeric
  data$columnX <- as.numeric(data$columnX)

  # return dataset
  return(data)

}
```

I get the following error:

```
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: value1, value2, value3
Error: Assigned data `as.numeric(data$columnX)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 10000 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `columnX`.
```

I've tried it with a single value1 where value1 <- c("rural" = 1, "suburban" = 2, "urban" = 3)

I know I can just:

```
df$Area <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$Area))
```

the data but I want specific values for each choice rather than R choosing.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using `dplyr` instead of `plyr`? I think using `dplyr`'s `across`-function could be useful here.

Comment: @MartinGal, thanks for your reply. I am using dplyr in other sections of my code, so not using plyr would simplify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by @MartinGal in his comment, `plyr` is retired and the package authors themselves recommend using `dplyr` instead. See https://github.com/hadley/plyr.

Hence, one option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `dplyr::recode`. Additionally if you want to write your function I would suggest to pass the values to recode and the replacements as vectors instead of passing each value and replacement as separate arguments:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  Area = sample(c("rural", "suburban", "urban"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

recode_table <- c("rural" = 1, "suburban" = 2, "urban" = 3)

recode(df$Area, !!!recode_table)
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 3

reval_3 <- function(data, x, values, replacements) {
  recode_table <- setNames(replacements, values)  
  data[[x]] <- recode(data[[x]], !!!recode_table)
  data
}

df <- reval_3(df, "Area", c("rural", "suburban", "urban"), 1:3)
df
#>    Area
#> 1     1
#> 2     1
#> 3     1
#> 4     1
#> 5     2
#> 6     2
#> 7     2
#> 8     1
#> 9     3
#> 10    3
```

Comment: Stefan, thanks for your solution. I will used dplyr and drop plyr  and test/use your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when` with `across`.

If the columns that you want to change are called `col1`, `col2` you can do -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(col1, col2), ~case_when(. == 'rural' ~ 1, 
                          . == 'suburban' ~ 2, 
                          . == 'urban' ~ 3)))
```

Based on your actual column names you can also pass `starts_with`, `ends_with`, range of columns `A:Z` in `across`.